# RestKit mapping error when sending image with RKObjectMapping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, restkit

Here is the object RestKit mapping:-

```
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ImageModel class]];

[mapping mapKeyPath:@"Description" toAttribute:@"description"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"Photo1"  toAttribute:@"photo1"];

[objectManager.mappingProvider addObjectMapping:mapping];

RKObjectMapping* serializeMapping = [mapping inverseMapping];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:serializeMapping forClass:[ImageModel class]];
[objectManager.router routeClass:[ImageModel class] toResourcePath:@"/image" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:mapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/image"];
```

And here is the ImageModel  object:-

```
@property  (strong,nonatomic) NSString *description; 
@property  (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *photo1;
```

Here are three different ways that i have tried but all with errors:-

Method1.

Simply use the following code to post object.

```
obj.description = self.descriptionText.text;
obj.photo1 = selectedImage;
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:obj delegate:self];
```

Result:-
 The object is posted to the server and the server script returns the same object back. The response is received at the client side but the following mapping related exception occurred.

```
2012-10-26 20:16:39.015 APP[4548:7407] W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:244 Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'Photo1'. No strategy for transforming from '__NSCFString' to 'UIImage'
```

The log does show that the returned object's Photo1 field does have photo data, but what's missed from the mapping is not understandable. Any idea from RestKit gurus will be very helpful!

Method 2 - Call sendObject:toResourcePath:usingBlock

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] sendObject:self.obj toResourcePath:@"/image" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.targetObject = nil;
    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;

    if([obj photo1]){
        RKObjectMapping* serializationMapping = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] serializationMappingForClass:[ImageModel class]];
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSDictionary* dictionary = [[RKObjectSerializer serializerWithObject:obj mapping:serializationMapping] serializedObject:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
        RKParams* params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:dictionary];
        NSData* imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation([obj photo1]);
        [params setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/png" forParam:@"Photo1"];
        loader.params = params;
    }
}];
```

Result:
Following error appears in the log window.

```
2012-10-26 20:32:15.327 APP[4627:c07] response code: 500
2012-10-26 20:32:22.388 APP[4627:c07] Loaded payload: {"Message":"An error has occurred."}
2012-10-26 20:32:27.878 APP[4627:c07] W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:87 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
2012-10-26 20:32:27.878 APP[4627:c07] E restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:231 Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
```

Method 3

Call postObject:usingBlock

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:obj usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader){

    loader.delegate = self;

    RKParams* params = [RKParams params];
    [params setValue:obj.description forParam:@"Description"];
    [params setData:[app convertImageToNSData: [app photo1]] MIMEType:@"image/png" forParam:@"Photo1"];        
    loader.params = params;
}];
```

Result:-
Following exceptions appear in the log window.

```
2012-10-26 20:42:07.735 APP[4670:c07] response code: 500
2012-10-26 20:42:10.726 APP[4670:c07] Loaded payload: {"Message":"An error has occurred."}
2012-10-26 20:42:16.569 APP[4670:c07] W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:87 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
2012-10-26 20:42:16.570 APP[4670:c07] E restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:231 Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
2012-10-26 20:42:16.570 APP[4670:c07] E restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:360 Encountered an error while attempting to map server side errors from payload: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
```

Apparently I am not missing anything in the mapping, but might I am . Can RestKit gurus help me any of these 3 methods to help me able to send an object having an image in one of it's fields to the server.